# Import Matlab Workspace variables into Spyder (Python)

Tags: python, matlab, translation, workspace, spyder

I'm translating a code from Matlab into Python, and there inevitably are some bugs. I'm going through the code comparing variables to ensure the methods are equivalent.

Is there a way to **import Matlab workspace variables into Spyder** (or the other way around) so I can do a **boolean truth comparison** for each variable?

Comment: Can you not just copy and paste them? I know you can copy out of and into MATLAB through the variable editor... Otherwise maybe export them to something standard like JSON?

Comment: Tried copy and pasting. Will try JSON Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the Matlab workspace as .mat file at 'File Location'

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
f = h5py.File('File Location')
matlab_arr=f['array name']
matlab_arr=np.array(matlab_arr,dtype='f8')
```

Could then do a comparison with:

```
(matlab_arr==python_arr).all()
```

or

```
np.isclose(matlab_arr, python_arr).all()
```